# jQuery button box shadow color picker

Tags: jquery

I am working on button generator and i am trying to target the box shadow color that could be change with color picker.  could anyone help me with the color picker and targeting the hex value. i am using jsColor lib at the moment for changing the button color but i cant get it working for the box shadow and then text shadow.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cuZsK/ my jsfiddle project

Comment: Where's your color picker? or is that what you're asking for help with?

Answer (score 0):

Simply using the [jscolor docs](http://jscolor.com/) should get you started. In order to update the shadow dynamically, you can specify parameters within the class attribute of your input element, e.g. `color {onImmediateChange:'updateColor();'}` will call `updateColor()` while the user drags the mouse over colors. Here's a functional fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/cuZsK/1/